# Azure DevOps : Pull Request across the Repositories?

Tags: azure-devops, repository, pull-request

I am not sure if people usually maintain the Production branch and other Development/Developer specific branches in the same Repository, but I want to have separate Production only Repository.

Now, in that case, how do I keep updating the code in my Production repository/branch?

If it is the same Repository, then I can create a Pull request across branches and keep the branch / code up to date or in sync.

But, how do I keep pushing the new code modifications to the branch in a different Repository?
For the initial copy, there is "Clone" feature, but I am not aware if pull is also possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's a weird thing to want to do. You *could* fork your repo and do PRs to and from the fork, but I'd recommend that you just keep all the branches in the same repo unless you have a really compelling reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Azure DevOps : Pull Request across the Repositories?

You can do such operation in Azure Devops. **BUT**, the **prerequisite** is there must exist **Fork** relationship between current(`Repos-A`) and target(`Repos-B`) repos.

In other words, one repo must **be forked from** another repo if you want to create pull request across repos.

[image]

At this time, you will have an option to choose another repos/project while you creating the Pull request.

[image]

---

As normal, we do not recommend such operation. In this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio), we described a particular scenario:

> For a very small team (2-5 developers), we recommend working in a
> single repo. Everyone should work in topic branches, and master should
> be protected with branch policies. As your team grows larger, you may
> find yourself outgrowing this arrangement and prefer to switch to a
> forking workflow.
>
> If your repository has a large number of casual or infrequent
> committers (similar to an open source project), we recommend the
> forking workflow. Typically only core contributors to your project
> have direct commit rights into your repository. You should ask
> collaborators from outside this core set of people to work from a fork
> of the repository. This will isolate their changes from yours until
> you've had a chance to vet the work.