# copy feature branch code into master branch of another repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm looking for steps to push feature branch on repository A to master branch of repository B using command line steps on azure DevOps build pipeline.
Thanks

Comment: How well this will work depends on how similar the two repositories are.

Comment: Did this two repository in the same team project or same collection in Azure DevOps Sever?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, its in the same team project of same collection of azure devops server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, in the comments. everything command is coming as single line.
So, here it is again.

here, is the git commands which fixed the ask for me.

## to clone single feature branch from Repo A

git clone -b feature/feature-test --single-branch

## creating a new branch with name as master.

git checkout -b master

## adding remote url of Repo B

git remote add origin-feature

## pushing to Repo B

git push origin-feature master

Comment: Thanks for your kindly sharing.You could *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is through Pull Request. But it depends if there exist **Fork** relationship between current(repoA) and target(repoB) repos.

In other word, one repos must **be forked from** another repos if you want to create pull request across repos.

[image]

At this time, you will has option to choose another repos/project while you creating the Pull request.

[image]

More details please take a look at the answer in this question: [Azure DevOps : Pull Request across the Repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590177/azure-devops-pull-request-across-the-repositories)

Otherwise you need to use multiple git commands to achieve this:

1. Separately Clone the repoA  and repoB to your local machine.

   `git clone {repo urla}
    git clone {repo urlb}`
2. Go to the local repo and move to the feature branch.

   `git checkout {feature branch}`
3. Copy all the content - `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C`.
4. Move back to master branch in repoB.

   `git checkout master`
5. Paste the files (and replace existing files) `Ctrl+V`.
6. Commit the changes.

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "update master"`
7. Push the changes to remote repoB inAzure DevOps .

   `git push`

Now the `master` branch updated with the content of the `feature branch`.

---

Besides, you could also try to use this 3-rd party extension --[Git Merge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dtzar.git-merge) in marketplace.

> Test merges for conflicts between git branches OR actual merge commit
>   and push of two git branches

Comment: Hi Patrick,

I followed up on your idea with other answers. here, is the git commands which fixed the answer for me.

git clone -b feature/feature-test --single-branch <Repo A>

git checkout -b master

git remote add origin-feature <Repo B>

git push origin-feature master

#checkout feature branch; earlier it was master
git checkout feature/feature-test

Comment: I think for people not familiar with git, what needs to be left out in ctrl + a, ctrl + c is the .git file.  I believe the .git file needs to be intact in the designated folder where files to be pasted.